# Grails Postgres validation query. Failed to validate a newly established connection

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, validation, grails, grails-orm

So I've got this issue which I really don't understand.

I've got a grails application running 3.3.0 and the following properties:

```
    dataSource:
        dbCreate: update
        url: jdbc:postgresql://***********:5432/*******
        username: ************
        password: *************
        driverClassName: org.postgresql.Driver
        pooled: true
        properties:
            timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis: 1000 * 60 * 30
            minEvictableIdleTimeMillis: 1000 * 60 * 30
            validationQuery: "SELECT 1"
            validationQueryTimeout: 30
            validationInterval: 15000
            testOnBorrow: true
            testWhileIdle: true
            testOnReturn: true
```

Now when the application tries to validate I get the following exception :

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Failed to validate a newly established connection.
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:840)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:651)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.getConnection(ConnectionPool.java:198)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:132)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy$LazyConnectionInvocationHandler.getTargetConnection(LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy.java:403)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy$LazyConnectionInvocationHandler.invoke(LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy.java:376)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy74.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor164.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy$TransactionAwareInvocationHandler.invoke(TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy.java:240)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy74.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$5.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:146)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:172)
        ... 44 common frames omitted
```

I've tried changing the validation query to

`SELECT 1 FROM`
`SELECT now()`
`SELECT VERSION`

I also removed the quotes from the validation query parameter but no luck.

Running all of these queries directly on the DB produce the desired output.

Am I missing something really simple?!

Comment: Maybe try to add " dialect : org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect" under dataSource.

Comment: The dialect is specified in the config but on a general DataSource, this datasource I pasted here is the production datasource.

Comment: Does anybody have any idea whats causing this? Is it a tomcat issue?